# Consumer receiving messages before all replicas acknowledge to leader kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Let's say high watermark for topic partition is 1000 and leader, all follower replicas have same messages exactly. In this scenario, producer sends a message with `acks = all` and a consumer is consuming from this topic. Is there a possibility here, where a consumer fetch request will be served before other replicas fetch request?

In other words, does leader serve consumer's fetch request before it receives acknowledgements from all in-sync followers in `acks = all` case?

This is because in our setup, consumer received a message before followers in `acks=all` case.

Answer (score 1):

In Kafka a message is ready to be consumed after it is added to leader broker, but if you set `acks=all` leader will wait all **in-sync-replicas** to replicate message.

Normally it is expected that all replicas of a topic would be in-sync-replicas unless there is a problem in replication process. (if some of replicas become out-of-sync, you can still continue to produce messages if you have enough replicas (`min.insync.replicas`) even if you set `acks=all`)

> **min.insync.replicas**: When a producer sets acks to "all" (or "-1"),
>   min.insync.replicas specifies the minimum number of replicas that must
>   acknowledge a write for the write to be considered successful. If this
>   minimum cannot be met, then the producer will raise an exception
>   (either NotEnoughReplicas or NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppend).

In your case it seems there is no way to bypass replication process if you set `acks=all`. But you can set `acks=1` if you don't want to wait for replication process. With this config a message would be available to consumers right after leader write the message to its local log. (followers will also replicate messages, but leader will not wait them) But you should consider the risk of data loss with this config.

> **acks=1** This will mean the leader will write the record to its local
>   log but will respond without awaiting full acknowledgement from all
>   followers. In this case should the leader fail immediately after
>   acknowledging the record but before the followers have replicated it
>   then the record will be lost

Comment: I had another observation which supports my point.
For a topic with replication factor > 1, We did a test to measure round trip time (client1 -> kafka -> client2 -> kafka -> client1) of messages with both acks = 1 and acks = all , and observed latency to be same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/producer.html), it's clearly mentioned that the message will be ready for consumption when all in-sync replicas get the message.

> Messages written to the partition leader are not immediately readable by consumers regardless of the producer’s acknowledgement settings. When all in-sync replicas have acknowledged the write, then the message is considered committed, which makes it available for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are observing this behavior because you left the `min.insync.replicas` to the default value which is 1.
The leader partition is included in the `min.insync.replicas` count, so it means that with `min.insync.replicas = 1`, it's just the leader that needs to do the write (then acks the producer) and then the message is available to the consumer; it's actually not waiting for the message to be replicated to other followers because the criteria on `min.insync.replicas` are already met. It makes `acks=all` the same as `acks=1`.
You will see a difference if you increase the `min.insync.replicas > 1`.